# Why are values for DeviceMotionEvent's accelerationIncludingGravity different between iOS and Android?

Tags: javascript, html, motionevent

I have a page that looks at motion events.  For some reason, the values returned on iOS devices vs Android devices (Galaxy S4 specifically) are different - essentially opposite of one another.

So for example if, `accelerationIncludingGravity.y` is 50 on the iPhone 5s, it'll be -50 on the Galaxy S4.  I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaF8k/) to demonstrate the problem.

My questions:

1. Am I missing something simple?
2. Which device is correct?

Comment: I have a same problem with you,if you know the answer,please tell me as soon as posibble,thank you

Comment: Same here. Have added a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how each vendor aligns the direction axis. This "problem" was going on for quite some time now. What most people end up doing, is wrapping your acceleration code in a class that has device detection. Transforming it into a more uniform format and then working with that in your application.

This is very simple, yet practical approach.

Comment: Given this is at a vendor-level, is it safe to assume that all androids, regardless of browser (chrome, firefox, native) will all have the same acceleration direction, because this is at the hardward/OS level, rather than at the browser?

Comment: Based on my experience with this, I can say that yes, it is browser independent for all major hardware vendors.

Answer (score 0):

As reported on [w3.org forum](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-geolocation/2014Nov/0000.html), there is a discrepancy between the Chrome Android, and the Safari iOS implementations.

Currently Android orients gravity in the same manner as the specification, with a flat device reporting

```
accelerationIncludingGravity: {x: 0, y: 0, z:9.81}
```

However on iOS the gravity is reversed, which reports

```
accelerationIncludingGravity: {x: 0, y: 0, z: -9.81}.
```

Device checking should be implemented to fix this issue.